# How common is onomatopoeia in English?

Tags: frequency

My intuition is that onomatopoeia is quite rare and that the letters and sounds of most words are meaningless (e.g. if "chicken" and "fish" were switched all along, no one would think "That word doesn't sound like it tastes").

But I want to have **data about the exact frequency** of onomatopoeic words (or is that a spectrum rather than binary?) both (1) as a proportion of a reference vocabulary, such as a dictionary (e.g. "10% of all words are onomatopoeic"), and (2) as a proportion in spoken or written usage.

Does such a corpus annotated with the property "this word is onomatopoeic" exist and what are those frequencies (if they are public I can calculate that myself also)?

Comment: You appear to have the wrong idea of what _onomatopoeia_ is; the fact that language is **sound** is what allows onomatopoeia -- i.e, sounds that refer recursively to sounds, by imitation. _Onomatopoeia_ is not the same thing as sound symbolism, which is what you appear to be asking about. Sound symbolism is not recursive or imitative, but rather associates certain specific sounds with certain meanings, like the [_KL-_ words in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf).

Comment: I think Konrad does understand onomatopoeia as imitation.  'Fish' may have some relation to 'splash', and 'chick' and 'cluck' are probably imitations of poultry sounds.

Comment: How common is onomatopoiea in your native language? By frequency do you mean number of lexical entries in a dictionary or number of tokens in a corpus? You can probably do this yourself by getting hold of the OED  which may (or may not) have onomatopoia as a tag on each word, and then count, but then also count those instance in a corpus. Since ono... (gah that word is too long) is fairly rare, I doubt you'd have to worry about ambiguity for the same uttereance for non-ono uses. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Note the description as a 'spectrum' is relevant - e.g. Japanese classifies its onomatopoeia as 擬声語 and 擬音語 'onomatopoeic words', but there are also 擬態語, 擬容語 and 擬情語. Different definitions of onomatopoeia can thus be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Some English words seem to be onomatopoeic. The word "purr" is like the sound made by a contented cat, and "spank" resembles the sound made by my girlfriend's hand impacting on my bottom when she is annoyed with me.

I am not sure if onomatopoeia is all that common though. Most English words are derived from Proto-Indoeuropean and have changed their form considerably in the course of the centuries. If a modern English word seems to be onomatopoeic, it does not necessarily follow that the Proto-IE root was also onomatopoeic.

And even it was, it still does not prove that the word was originally onomatopoeic. Proto-IE was not the "Ursprache", the orginal language spoken by humankind. The proto-IE roots may well have changed their form since their origin in some long forgotten pre-Indoeuropean language.

Answer (score -2):

Onomatapoeia is actually very common in English, especially (naturally) for sounds (crash, bang) and animal noises (squeak, snort), but also for words that directly or suggestively involve sound
or other sensory associations (clap, pluck, swim, swerve, flee, fly). My guess is that English is one of the most onomatapoeic of languages.

Comment: What is the basis for your "guess"?

Comment: swim, swerve, flee, & fly all have well established etymologies back in PIE. If they're onomatopoeias, they're very ancient ones. The last two also don't bear much resemblance to their original form (both come from different forms of the root *plewk-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).